# What's the proper way of terminating a Node.js server request?

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I'm playing around with a basic Node.js server (no frameworks). I want the server to terminate the request under certain conditions. What's the proper way of doing this? I tried `request.connection.destroy()`, `req.removeListener('data')`, and `req.removeListener('end')`,  but the server keeps going and returns results. Here's part of what I have:

```
http.createServer(function(req,res){
    req.on('data',function(data){
        content+=data;
        if(condition){
            req.connection.destroy();
            req.removeListener('data');
            req.removeListener('end');
        }
    });

    req.on('end',function(){=
        res.writeHead(200,{
            'Context-Type':'text/plain',
        });
        res.write(content);
        res.end();
    });
});
```

P.S. Isn't it better to do `req.once('end',...)` instead of `req.on('end',...)`? Everyone one else seems to use `on()`, is there a reason for that?

**Edit:**
I changed the `if` body to:

```
                req.abort();
                req.connection.destroy();
                req.removeAllListeners('data');
                req.removeAllListeners('end');
```

However, the `end` event is still being called (i.e. `content` is still being written).

Comment: Doesn't `removeListener` take the listener itself as an argument?

Answer (score 1):

You should call req.abort();

Documentation here:
https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_abort

Answer (score 0):

You must return any result. This is only proper way. Your client send request to server so it need to answer. It can be status 400 but it has to be. In the other way your client will never realize that request has been terminated and slow down your app.